# Hatcher's Algebraic Topology - Example 0.6: Constructing $\Bbb CP^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space, spheres

Here is the construction of $\Bbb CP^n$ explained in Hatcher book (p. 7):

> It is also possible to obtain $\Bbb CP^n$ as a
>   quotient space of the disk $D^{2n}$ under the identifications $v\sim \lambda v$ for $v\in \partial D^{2n}$, in the
>   following way. The vectors in $\Bbb S^{2n+1}\subset \Bbb C^{n+1}$ with last coordinate real and nonnegative
>   are precisely the vectors of the form $(w, \sqrt{1-|w|^2})\in \Bbb C^n\times \Bbb  C$ with $|w|\leq 1$. Such
>   vectors form the graph of the function $w\mapsto \sqrt{1-|w|^2}$. This is a disk $D_+^{2n}$
>   bounded
>   by the sphere $\Bbb S^{2n-1}\subset\Bbb S^{2n+1}$ consisting of vectors $(w, 0)\in \Bbb C^n\times \Bbb  C$ with $|w|= 1$. Each
>   vector in $\Bbb S^{2n-1}$ is equivalent under the identifications $v\sim \lambda v$ to a vector in $D_+^{2n}$, and
>   the latter vector is unique if its last coordinate is nonzero. If the last coordinate is
>   zero, we have just the identifications $v\sim \lambda v$ for $v\in \Bbb S^{2n-1}$.

I don't understand why the dimension of the above disk is $2n$? (and of course the dimension  of the $\Bbb S^{2n-1}$) I think it (dimension of above disk)  should be $2n+1$ because it is the upper hemisphere of $\Bbb S^{2n+1}$. What is the wrong?

Comment: $\Bbb S^{2n+1}$ has dimension $2n+1$, and we 'lose a dimension' when we restrict the last coordinate to be real (positive). Also, the graph of the map $\Bbb C^n\to \Bbb R$ is (locally) like its domain, having $2n$ dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in fact a little confusing. The point is to understand $S^{2n+1}$. Obviously we have
$$S^{2n+1} = \{ (z_1,\ldots,z_{n+1}) \in \mathbb C^{n+1} \mid \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lvert z_i \rvert^2 = 1 \} .$$
Hatcher considers the subset
$$S =  \{(z_1,\ldots,z_{n+1}) \in S^{2n+1} \mid \text{Im}(z_{n+1}) = 0, \text{Re}(z_{n+1}) \ge 0\} .$$
But $S' = \{(z_1,\ldots,z_{n+1}) \in S^{2n+1} \mid \text{Im}(z_{n+1}) = 0 \}$ is nothing else than a copy of $S^{2n} \subset \mathbb R^{2n+1} = \mathbb C^n \times \mathbb R$.

Thus $S$ is **not** the upper hemisphere of $S^{2n+1} \subset \mathbb R^{2n+2}$, but a copy of the upper hemisphere of $S^{2n} \subset \mathbb R^{2n+1}$. And this is clearly homeomorphic to a $2n$-dimensional disk.

More formally, the disk $D^{2n} \subset \mathbb C^n$ is homeomorphic to $S$ because it is the graph of the function $\phi : D^{2n} \to \mathbb C, \phi(w) = \sqrt{1-\lvert w \rvert}$.