# Why is $ \mathbb{RP}^3 $ NOT same as $ \mathbb{CP}^2 $?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, projective-space

We know that topologically $ \mathbb{R}^{2n} \simeq \mathbb{C}^n $ by, for example, $ (x_1, y_1, \dots, x_n, y_n) \mapsto (x_1 + i y_1, \dots, x_n + i y_n) $. The unit balls in two spaces, both of which are even called the same, $S^{2n-1}$, are also homeomorphic. Then, we get $ \mathbb{RP}^3 $ and $ \mathbb{CP}^2 $ by identifying antipodal points in here.

What is wrong with this argument? At least I know their fundamental groups are different, so they should not be homeomorphic. Moreover, generalizing the above argument, $ \mathbb{RP}^{2n-1} $ should be homeomorphic to $ \mathbb{CP}^n $ for every $n$, which is not the case as well. My chain of thought is just a generalization of what we do to show that $ \mathbb{RP}^1 $ is same as $ \mathbb{CP}^1 $, but I can't find what I am missing.

Comment: $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is not formed by identifying antipodal points: indeed it identifies a whole $\mathbb S^1$.

Comment: $\Bbb {CP}^n$ is not $S^{2n+1}$ quotiented by the antipodal relation. It's $S^{2n+1}$ quotiented by $z_1\sim z_2\Leftrightarrow \exists \theta\in\Bbb R, z_1=e^{i\theta}z_2$, which loosely corresponds to having a quotient map with fibers homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: ${\bf RP}^3$ has real dimension $3$, whereas ${\bf CP}^2$ has real dimension $4$. Maybe you meant ${\bf RP}^{\color{red}4}$? But then, one is orientable and the other not.

Comment: [see this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570701/hatchers-algebraic-topology-example-0-6-constructing-bbb-cpn-from-d2n/3570736#comment7342186_3570736)

Comment: $ \mathbb{RP}^1 $ is not the same as $ \mathbb{CP}^1 $. The first is homeomorphic to $S^1$, the second to $S^2$.